# Is there any written evidence of NASA being under pressure to launch prior to the Rogers Commission asserting it in February, 1986?

Tags: nasa, space-shuttle

I asked that question of the NASA administrator, James M Beggs and got the following response.

> JRG:  *Jim a lot has been made of the fact that NASA management made
> poor decisions regarding the Challenger launch due to being under extreme pressure to meet a launch
> schedule.   Did you feel pressure to launch?*
>
> JMB:  *Only mildly.  No more than I felt with GD (General Dynamics).   Every organization
> has a production goal they are working towards, that creates pressure
> to reach that goal.   We could have flown 10 flights in 1986 and the
> President and Congress would not have objected.*
>
> JRG:  *What was your biggest concern regarding flights in 1986?*
>
> JMB:  *We were struggling to find enough payload to fill out the
> flights.  Flight crews and Mission Specialists were easy, we had a
> long line of people wanting to go up.    The problem was the shuttle
> was designed primarily as a payload vehicle not a passenger vehicle.
>
> The Air Force had demanded we make 12 flights a year available to them
> and they only had enough cargo for 3 or 4  a year.   Commercial
> payloads were a big focus, but took time to develop.  Some flights at
> the end of 1985  flew with less than half of the payload they could
> have carried.*
>
> JRG:  *So the NASA you lead faced the same challenges as a private
> airline.  Have enough available capacity to meet customer demand, but
> not schedule so many flights that you can’t effectively fill them.*
>
> JMB:  *Right, Pan Am was handling some of our manifesting, so that is
> pretty accurate.*

Does anyone have documentation of NASA officials or the press speaking of pressure to launch, prior to the Rogers Commission creating that story?

Comment: Source of this quoted material?

Comment: Transcript of phone call with James Beggs on 9/20/18 at 1:28PM

Comment: What is the "Challenger Truth"? If the system was under no pressure to launch, why did they do it?  Wouldn't it be more effective to set up a website somewhere and explain your views, rather than going through this Socratic questioning process?

Comment: The Challenger Truth is that it was a completely unexpected failure caused by a processing error on 12/7/86.   It was an accident...

Comment: The reason for asking this question is to try to uncover information that supports the  "known" truth.   I am unable to locate any and hope others can provide me with something I missed.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your views. I don't agree with them, but it puts your questions into context.

Comment: You wouldn't so long as you are trapped in the world of the Cold O-ring theory.   Go read Appendix C... https://history.nasa.gov/rogersrep/v1appc.htm

Comment: When reading Appendix C, make sure you don't get fooled by the way the Commission attempted to hide the stacking theory.   Everything in Appendix C before 51L Booster processing appeared on the first page of the Appendix and would cause any normal reader to skip reading Appendix C.   The second page onward is what they didn't want you to read.

Comment: I kind of agree- these specific questions (on a highly touchy, for lack of a better word, subject for a lot of users), whats the purpose? I feel like anything you could learn with a FOIA request would seem to serve your purpose better but you'd have to be specific.

Comment: What is so touchy about finding the truth.  When the head of MSFC engineering, Jim Kingsbury, says the Rogers Commission report is a managed document and the SRB joint was responding the same way on 1/28/86 that it would have on 8/28/86, I for one am curious.   I don't like being told to believe a cold O-ring explanation that doesn't fit any of the facts of the accident.   Those that like a simple common sense explanation can skip my questions, which challenge that comfort level.  With respect to the story that NASA management was under pressure to launch "WHERE'S THE BEEF"??

Comment: All I suggested was you go through official government channels to get information, as it may suit your purpose better than asking here. Mostly just asking if you've actually tried a FOIA request for these types of inquiries into publicly available government documents? Also, by "touchy" I meant some here may have had friends in that accident, it involved loss of life; nothing more. Official government channels are meant to be non-biased, here that's not the case.

Comment: I have sought to obtain information through visits to the National Archive and FOIA.   A prime example is my desire to obtain the original NASA accident analysis team report (unfiltered by the Rogers Commission).  My FOIA request was denied because information about SRB performance could be used by enemies of the United States.     With respect to the second part of your comment, I quote the Feynman character in the BBC Challenger movie  " I prefer to show my respect by finding the CAUSE of their appalling deaths and not stand around looking sad. "

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be a genuine question, but merely a soapbox for the author to present their personal opinions and theories. Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, not a blogging platform.

Comment: I disagree with the close-as-not-a-question votes. This *is* a question, even though the OP may have intended it as a soapbox. So, why not add a more mainstream answer and let the votes sort it out? Maybe a meta discussion would be useful.

Comment: There's still no relevant link in the question, so what telephone conversation are we talking about?

Comment: The head of NASA in a conversation indicates that he felt neither he nor his team were under any pressure to launch.   I asked a question to find out the basis for the belief that they were.    I got my answer, no one can cite a single article or statement prior to the accident that supported this myth.  Close the question, delete the information, go back to your discussion of "Nudism in space: Why wear clothes anyway?"   Much more valuable to understanding NASA and spaceflight.

Answer (score -3):

I had hoped that someone could provide a piece of evidence to support this claim. 
   It appears that it is in fact a “myth” created by the Rogers commission. The first appearance I can find of the “***Under Pressure***” theory (although maybe Queen was referring to NASA in their song)  is an article in the Washington Post on 2/9/86.

Why would the Commission create a theory that NASA (and MTI management) was under extreme pressure to launch when none of the Challenger decision makers felt that they were?

The cold O-ring explanation for the accident on its face assumes that everyone in the world knows that rubber responds slower to the cold temperatures, but not the decision makers.  The cold O-ring theory assumes that the launch decision makers ignored the obvious “fact” of O-ring response and proceeded to launch in spite of “clear” warnings.

The problem with that explanation is that the NASA management team did not appear to be the “idiots who launch in the cold” that this story requires them to be.   The theory works if you assert that the management team knew that the obvious cold O-ring risk was present, but they chose to take that risk due to an extreme pressure to launch.  Larry Mulloy, George Hardy, Bob Lund and Joe Kilminister have all denied on the record that they felt a pressure to launch.   And it appears that they were not under any pressure to launch.

Bob Lund, the key MTI decision maker,  chose to ignore the assertions of Roger Boisjoly and Arnie Thompson that the cold temperature could lead to a joint 
failure because the data they presented proved the exact opposite.  This “key” data was the resiliency tests done by Roger Boisjoly and Arnie Thompson in February, 1985.

The tests showed the following:
  [image: O-ring resiliency chart]

This data leads to the common sense conclusion that as the O-ring gets colder it takes significantly longer to seal.    It was then assumed that this property had “some significance” in the accident.

This data provides a second more important conclusion for anyone with a basic understanding of SRB joint dynamics.   A SRB joint must obtain a good seal in the first 400 milliseconds after ignition or it will suffer a catastrophic leak.  This test data indicates that if the joint relied on O-ring resiliency as the method of sealing then every joint under 75F would fail to seal before 2400 milliseconds.    Since 21 of the first 24 flights were under 75F and none of them failed, it is clear that some other method beside O-ring resiliency was the primary method of sealing the SRB joint.

Bob Lund and the other MTI managers knew this and  rejected the cold O-ring theory, not because of pressure to launch, but because the data presented did not support a conclusion that a SRB leak would occur.   The only reasonable conclusion you can draw from the data presented was the O-ring resiliency had nothing to do with SRB joint sealing below 75F.

**The answer to this question is**:   NASA and the MTI managers were, as they stated, under no pressure to launch.    They looked at the data presented which predicted a failure because of cold O-ring function and PROPERLY rejected it as a false conclusion

Unfortunately for them, others with much less understanding of SRB joint dynamics, picked up the same data and made this false conclusion an obvious “fact”.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question. You asked about pressure / expectation on NASA management, and then wrote an answer which talks about the materials properties of O-rings.

Comment: Please reread the first paragraph.  No mention of pressure to launch has been located prior to Sunday 2/9/86. Despite offering a bounty and giving this diverse and intelligent community an opportunity to respond, no evidence has been found.     That was the purpose of this question, to determine if I missed any evidence that might point to the Challenger launch decision makers being under excess pressure to launch.   The balance of the answer is simply to explain why the myth was created ex post facto..

Comment: You've still got 1 paragraph to say that you haven't found the thing you asked for, followed by 10 paragraphs of your speculations about why that might be the case.

Comment: Not speculation.   I have 13 hours of phone conversation and 132 emails between myself and Bob Lund.    He and I discussed the details of his decision and the vicious attack he suffered as a result of making the right decision based upon the facts he was presented with.  He was a good and decent man who doesn't deserve the label placed on him.  Forgive me for wanting to defend him.